# Simple n-body class in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, simulation, physics

As part of my training, I implemented a n-body class in C++ to simulate gravitational interaction of bodies and to get more familiar with features that C++ offers such as object oriented programming.

This implementation uses a direct integration (Verlet integration) of the differential equations which results in a time complexity of \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$, where \$n\$ is the number of particles.

Please be as hard as possible with this implementation and give me constructive feedback.

I would appreciate advice especially in the following areas:

1. Code style (readability, naming conventions)
2. Class design
3. Efficieny (how to avoid unnecessary complexity)
4. Reinventing the wheel (does the STL offer functionality I should use in my code?)
5. Memory usage

**main.cpp**

```
#include "nbody.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Nbody nbody(16, 0.001, 1);
    nbody.timeIntegration();
    return 0;
}
```

**nbody.h**

```
#ifndef NBODY_H
#define NBODY_H

// Parameters
const int DIM = 2;          // dimensions
const double EPS = 1e-4;    // smoothing parameter

// Function prototypes
inline double sqr(double);

struct Particle{
    double m;           // mass
    double x[DIM];      // position
    double v[DIM];      // velocity
    double F[DIM];      // force 
    double F_old[DIM];  // force past time step
};

// Nbody class 
class Nbody {
    private:
        int step = 0;
        double t = 0;
        const int n;         // number of particles
        const double dt;           // step size
        const double t_max;        // max simulation time
        Particle *p = new Particle[n]; // allocate memory 
        void init_data();
    public:
        ~Nbody();
        Nbody(int n_, double dt_, double t_max_);
        inline void print_parameter() const;
        inline void print_data() const;
        inline void write_data(int step) const;
        void timeIntegration();
        void comp_force();
        void force(Particle*, Particle*);
        void comp_position();
        void comp_velocity();
        void update_position(Particle*);
        void update_velocity(Particle*);
};

#endif
```

**nbody.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

#include "nbody.h"

// Class methods
Nbody::Nbody(int n_, double dt_, double t_max_) : n(n_), dt(dt_), t_max(t_max_) {
    init_data();
}

Nbody::~Nbody() {
    delete[] p; 
    p = 0; 
}

void Nbody::timeIntegration() {
    comp_force();
    for(; t<t_max; t+=dt, step+=1) {
        comp_position();
        comp_force();
        comp_velocity();
        if (step % 10 == 0) {
            write_data(step);
            //print_data();
        }
    }
}

void Nbody::update_velocity(Particle *p) {
    double a = dt * 0.5 / p->m;
    for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        p->v[d] += a * (p->F[d] + p->F_old[d]);
    }
}

void Nbody::update_position(Particle *p) {
    double a = dt * 0.5 / p->m;
    for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        p->x[d] += dt * (p->v[d] + a * p->F[d]);
        p->F_old[d] = p->F[d];
    }
}

void Nbody::comp_velocity() {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        update_velocity(&p[i]);
    }
}

void Nbody::comp_position() {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        update_position(&p[i]);
    }
}

void Nbody::comp_force() {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
            p[i].F[d] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
            force(&p[i], &p[j]);
        }
    }
}

void Nbody::force(Particle *i, Particle *j) {
    double r=EPS; // smoothing
    for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        r += sqr(j->x[d] - i->x[d]);
    }
    double f = i->m * j->m / (sqrt(r) * r);
    for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
        i->F[d] += f * (j->x[d] - i->x[d]);
        j->F[d] -= f * (j->x[d] - i->x[d]);
    }
}

void Nbody::write_data(int step) const {
    std::ofstream results;
    std::string file_name = "data_" + std::to_string(step) + ".log";
    results.open(file_name);
    if (results.fail()) { // or (!results) ?
        std::cerr << "Error\n" << std::endl;
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            results << t << " ";
            results << p[i].m << " ";
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << p[i].x[d] << " ";
            }
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << p[i].v[d] << " ";
            }
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << p[i].F[d] << " ";
            }
            results << std::endl;
        }
        results.close();
    }
}

void Nbody::print_data() const {
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);
    std::cout.precision(5);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        std::cout << t << " ";
        std::cout << p[i].m << " ";
        for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
            std::cout << p[i].x[d] << " ";
        }
        for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
            std::cout << p[i].v[d] << " ";
        }
        for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
            std::cout << p[i].F[d] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Nbody::init_data() {
    std::random_device rd;          
    std::mt19937 generator(rd()); 
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution_x(0.0,1.0);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution_v(-1.0,1.0);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        p[i].m = 1./n;
        for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
            p[i].x[d] = distribution_x(generator);
            p[i].v[d] = distribution_v(generator);
            p[i].F[d] = 0.0;
            p[i].F_old[d] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

inline void Nbody::print_parameter() const {
    std::cout << n << " " << dt << " " << t_max << std::endl;
}

// Other Functions

inline double sqr(double x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

Comment: @Samuel If you want to provide more information, I think it'd be great to have an explanation of what is the N body simulation. This way, people could understand what your code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: Do you have a specific version of C++ you are targeting (C++11, C++14, C++17)?

Comment: @pacmaninbw I'm not sure which version to take. What makes sense? Which version should I use when writing a C++ programm?

Comment: You can add the comments, but at this point don't change the code. The version you should probably learn and use at this point is C++17.

Comment: @Samuel after considering our review feedback and possibly incorporating it into your code, you are very welcome to post it in a follow-up question. I am interested in how this piece of code develops further.

Comment: Just curious, based on what I see everything is in a single plane (I see x and y axis's but not the z axis). Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @pacmaninbw For `DIM=3` the simulation is three dimensional.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### The Great!

You're not making the basic beginner error of using `using namespace std;`! The `main()` function is only 3 lines of code.

The function declarations in the `nbody` class that don't change things include `const` which will help optimization later.

The code utilizes the C++ random number generation rather than the C `srand()` and `rand()` functions.

Because Nbody was implemented as a class it is very easy to change `main()` so that it can accept user input for the values of `n`, `dt` and `t_max`.

### Missing Header

The `#include <string>` is missing from `nbody.cpp`; this is necessary when compiling the code in most cases.

### The Obsolete

The use of `inline` function declarations is [now only a suggestion to the compiler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). Optimizing compilers can and will do a better job of optimizing by inlining code based.

The body of the `Nbody` constructor uses an obsolete form of initialization, rather than using `()` as in the following code

```
Nbody::Nbody(int n_, double dt_, double t_max_) : n(n_), dt(dt_), t_max(t_max_) {
    init_data();
}
```

use braces `{}`:

```
Nbody::Nbody(int n_, double dt_, double t_max_)
: n{n_}, dt{dt_}, t_max{t_max_}
{
    init_data();
}
```

Putting the initialization on a separate line makes it easier to find.

### Prefer STL Container Classes

Prefer STL container classes such as `std::vector` or `std::array` over old C style arrays. The `std::array<type, size>` class is a fixed size array. The `std::vector<type>` is a variable sized array. STL container classes provide iterators so that pointers aren't necessary. The use of `std::vector<Particle> p;` might reduce the number of parameters to the constructor. It would definitely remove the need for the variable `n` within the `Nbody` class since `p.size()` would always contain the number of particles after `Nbody::init_data()` has run. Also after `Nbody::init_data()` has run iterators could be used to access the particles in `p` and would allow the code to use a ranged for loop such as

```
void Nbody::write_data(int step) const {
    std::ofstream results;
    std::string file_name = "data_" + std::to_string(step) + ".log";
    results.open(file_name);
    if (results.fail()) { // or (!results) ?
        std::cerr << "Error\n" << std::endl;
    } else {
        for (auto particle : p) {
            results << t << " ";
            results << particle.m << " ";
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << particle.x[d] << " ";
            }
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << particle.v[d] << " ";
            }
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << particle.F[d] << " ";
            }
            results << std::endl;
        }
        results.close();
    }
}
```

Another benefit of making `p` an STL container class is that the destructor for the class `Nbody` can then be a default constructor and the array of particles doesn't need to be allocated in the class declaration.

### Variable Names

It's not really clear by just reading the code what the variables `n_`, `n`, `dt_`, `dt`, `t_max_`, `t_max`, `x`, `F` and `v` and `p` are. For instance, I assume `dt` means Delta Time, but it is not clear that this is true. The array `p` might be renamed `particles`, if I'm correct about `dt` than deltaTime might be more appropriate.

Yes there are comments for some of the variable names, but if I had to maintain the code I'd rather work with code that was self-documenting than depending on comments.

Example

```
void Nbody::write_data(int step) const {
    std::ofstream results;
    std::string file_name = "data_" + std::to_string(step) + ".log";
    results.open(file_name);
    if (results.fail()) { // or (!results) ?
        std::cerr << "Error\n" << std::endl;
    } else {
        for (auto particle : particles) {
            results << t << " ";
            results << particle.mass << " ";
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << particle.position[d] << " ";
            }
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << particle.velocity[d] << " ";
            }
            for (int d=0; d<DIM; d++) {
                results << particle.Force[d] << " ";
            }
            results << std::endl;
        }
        results.close();
    }
}
```

### Style

Some, not all, developers prefer to see the public declarations of a class before the private declarations of a class. This is because it becomes easier to find the public interface of the class.

The function `void init_data()` is not necessary unless you are planning to have multiple constructors, it might be better to move that code into the constructor.

If the functions `print_parameter()` and `print_data()` are debug functions it might be better to put them within `#ifdef DEBUG` and `#endif`.

In the current implementation `return 0;` from `main()` is not necessary. If error handling code is added and there is a `return 1;` it might be better to keep it. It might also be better to use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` and `EXIT_FAILURE` which are defined in `cstdlib` (`#include <cstdlib>`).

### Suggestions

It might be better to allow the user to name the output file that the results go into, either by input through a user interface or as part of the command line arguments. The name could default to the current file name in case the user doesn't specify one.

It might also be better to have only one output file.

Comment: The variable names are very self descriptive for this kind of domain in my opinion. I think it is also safe to assume that a maintainer of a n-body interaction program has a physics background.

Comment: You never know whos gonna maintain your code next. Might be a person with a totally different background. The cost for the naming the variables properly is neglible, but the potential benefit large.

Comment: @Hakaishin the cost is that anyone with the domain knowledge to maintain the code has to translate from the common notation of the domain, $dt$, each time they read the code. IMO this makes it less maintainable.

Comment: But you know what is the common notation of all domains? Language. Everybody understands velocity and I doubt that your thinking will be slower because you read a word which you understand instead of v. I might be touchy, because I had a project from an electrical engineer with many such short notation variables and I tool me a while to understand the code. As said my point above stands. But lets agree to disagree

Comment: @Hakaishin The physics equations use mathematical symbols (variables) and not their names and sentences for a reason. To make everything more readable. By using long names the code that implements mathematical equations (e.g. numerical methods) becomes *harder* to parse.

Comment: I've seen a lot of code with terse, mathematical-seeming variable names that were totally made-up (or came from one obscure paper), and _those_ codebases are terrible.  But `d` for change, and `t` for time, `m` for mass, `F` for force, etc., are really such basic, well-known notation.

Comment: I never really worked with containers before. Do I use `std::array` or `std::vector` in my case? Could you roughly sketch out how I'd have to adjust my code. Does moving `init_data()` into the constructor mean, that I define `init_data()` outside the class? Do I define `DEBUG` like `#define DEBUG TRUE`? Or how do I decide between debug and non-debug mode?

Comment: Because this is an N body simulation I would use `std::vector` because the size can change. Remove the variable `n` declaration from the `Nbody` class, in the constructor `n` will be still be input but it will only be used once as the number of times to create particles. SRP is mentioned in another answer, `Particle` should probably be promoted to a class and the constructor for that class should fill in the data fields for each particle, in that case the constructor for `Nbody` would just loop n times to create particles.

Comment: You can do the #define DEBUG TRUE, but a better way is to use the `-D` flag in the compiler command line.

Comment: @Samuel did you get my answers?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Yes, I'm still processing all that information.

Comment: Why the suggestion to use braces when parenthesis worked fine? I wouldn't call it obsolete.

Comment: Does it make more sense to use `for (const auto particle : particles)` instead of `for (auto particle : particles)` in this case? What about `for (const auto& particle : particles)`? Wouldn't that be the most efficient one?

Comment: Taken to the extreme, the variable names should be `velocity_component_in_meters_per_second`, but that would make me shudder. But re the claim that any later maintainer would have a physics background - it could just as well be someone who only wants to prettify output routines ... --- Oops! I just noted that `velocity_component_in_meters_per_second` would even be wrong as the code uses a gravitational constant of `1`; see, even I with physics background might have guessed a few things wrong during maintenance ...

Comment: @Samuel Your last question about efficiency would be answered in a code review of the new code once it is written, or you can get the answer on stack overflow. Many of us would like to see a second version of the code to continue helping you to improve your code. The new question should link to this question.

Answer (score 15):

## First Of All

You are doing a great job as a beginner. I have been programming for 10 years and my code for a long time was much, much less readable that what you have written. That said:

## What needs Fixing

I'm not privy of all of the details of the n-body problem but I have an idea of what it does. I'm not an expert on numerical accuracy so I won't comment on the arithmetic you are performing. Here are a few things that I see from a design perspective.

### This class is effectively Impossible to test

Between randomizing the input data upon construction and having one method that does the vast majority of the work, it is very difficult to write meaningful automated tests for this class. This is in part because this class does way too much.

### The Public interface does not reflect its usage

The public interface is much broader than what a client would use. As far as I can tell, the only thing a client would need to do is construct one of these objects and immediately call `timeIntegration()` upon it, then record the results somehow. More on this later.

### You use Non standard ways to convey standard concepts

You provide a "print_data" and a "write_data" method. The dependency on `<iostream>` & `<fstream>` is needless for this class and will make it very difficult to test in an automated (read: unit test) fashion. You should provide a `<<` operator for the particle class instead and allow the client to decide what to do with the results.

### There's no way to get at the raw data for this class

Furthermore, since the `print_data()` and `write_data()` methods are seemingly the only way get data from this class, the use of this class in anything other than a simple command prompt program is limited. A method to get the internal data in non-printed form would be helpful.

### What to do

A better design for this class may be a public constructor with the necessary parameters which immediately calls everything necessary to compute the integration, and then a method to get the data that has been processed. Nothing else would be public. This way, it is very difficult for a client to use this class incorrectly. A class with a getter for its only owned data should raise a red flag in an OOP design, so all of this rethinking is really leading to a bigger realization that...

## This shouldn't be a class

My biggest consideration would be to not have this be a class at all. None of the data that it owns are invariant across the useful public interface. [More on invariants in class design here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant). There is no reason for the state that has been introduced to be owned by this class across its lifetime and there are plenty of opportunities to use this class in ways that produce completely invalid data. This instead should have an interface that consists of one high, level function.

The public interface to the n-body calculator should take in two or three things:

1. A settings struct. This will include all necessary pieces to properly run the calculation other than the "hot" data. this will be initialized by the client. If the struct data is not valid (i.e. something that will be a denominator of zero), the function should exit with a return code of some sort (or exception if that's allowed in your environment and that's your thing). This should probably be taken by const l-value reference
2. A `std::vector<Particle>` by (possibly const l-value) reference, this is the input data to the n-body calculator
3. a time step to run for. This could be part of the settings struct, but in my mind it's distinctly different than the other concepts that would be in the settings struct.

This function should guarantee to either modify the `std::vector<Particle>` in place or return a transformed `std::vector<Particle>`. My personal preference is the latter, however depending on which version of C++ you are using, that can be inhibitive to good performance. In essence, all that this function is doing is transforming a list of particle states. It can (and should) use other helper functions to do its work, and these functions would very likely get reused in other parts of a larger particle framework. All functions should be stateless other than the particle set passed in.

The value add from this multi-fold:

1. It is more obvious how to use this interface correctly. See the principle of least surprise. [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).
2. It is much, much easier to test a set of stateless functions than it is to test a big, entangled class.
3. This will allow much higher reuse of basic operations as this code base expands.

## Other Suggestions

### Names

I would suggest better names for the `Particle` struct members. If they are used correctly in a larger program they will likely become ubiquitous as the base data types. There is nothing wrong with typing out mass, position, velocity and force. While it's true that people will probably know what you mean when you talk about position as x, they will definitely know what you mean when you type position.

### Strong Types

I would use strong types for the particle members. Jonathan Bocarra has some excellent blog articles on it on cppfluent (e.g. [CppFluent Strong types](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/)). They can be treated the same as doubles, with the advantage of making it much more difficult to switch arguments around in function calls, and making the code more expressive.

### Get Rid Of The Globals

Globals are a bad thing, and should be avoided. Regardless of whether the object-oriented approach is gotten rid of, these should be incorporated into a settings struct of some kind.

### Use the STL more than you are

A lot of your summing `for` loops can use `std::accumulate()`; you should be using `std::vector`s rather than raw c-style arrays. You should be using range-based `for` loops where you can't use `std::vector` or an STL algorithm.

Comment: You totally misunderstand the single responsibility principle.

Comment: You are right! I did. I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you! Great review in my opinion.

Answer (score 10):

Your code is written in a hybrid C/C++ style. For instance your destructor has a `delete` (I can't find where the corresponding `new` is) and that is basically never needed. Use a `std::vector` to store array-like data.

Also you do a lot of parameter passing like `void Nbody::update_position(Particle *p)`. Use references instead, and use `const Particle &p` if the particle is only read.

Otherwise it looks like an n-body code to me. It's quadratic rather than something more sophisticated/efficient, but that's probably ok.

Oh, I've found the `new`: you have
`Particle *p = new Particle[n];` 
in the class definition, but `n` is uninitialized. That is probably undefined behavior, definitely extremely dangerous, and most likely completely wrong.

Don't use `new` to allocate an array! Use `std::vector`, as follows:

````
std::vector<Particle> the_particles;
public:
  Particles(int n) : the_particles(vector<Particle>(n)) {}
}```
````

Comment: Indeed. As part of writing my answer, I refactored the code to use a `std::vector<Particle>`, and it felt much nicer.

Comment: I use `new` in the class definition. Did I use it the wrong way? What exactly is wrong with parameter passing? Don't I change the particle when I update it's velocity or position? Wouldn't it be wrong the use a constant reference then? Can you be more specific how `comp_velocity()` and `update_velocity()` would look like then?

Comment: Can you please explain your code in more detail? I am not very familiar with the STL. Do I define `std::vector<Particle> the_particles` as `private`? What exactly is `ParticleS`? Where is it defined? How do I use it in the rest of my code?

Comment: My compiler throws an error: `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
         Particle(int n) : p(vector<Particle>(n)) {};`. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. This uses C++17 idioms. Make sure to use the appropriate compiler flag!
2. Yes, make the vector private.
3. I used my own naming. It takes too much scrolling to find everything in your code. I'm sure you know what I mean.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers:

- Use unsigned integer type for `DIM`, `Nbody.step`, and `Nbody.n` since none of this can be negative;
- Use [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)<sup>since C++11</sup> instead just `const` for both `DIM` and `EPS`;
- Get rid of the unused `argc` and `argv` arguments in `main`;
- Consider more usage of `const`. For example `f` in `Nbody::force()` can be `const`, and `a` in `Nbody::update_position` can be `const` and so on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100289/discussion-on-answer-by-eanmos-simple-n-body-class-in-c).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the other answers:

The `init_data` function does not belong in the `Nbody` class. Nowhere in the definition of the N-body problem will you find the word "random", and using random input data is only connected to your particular situation, therefore this code should be moved into `main.cpp`.

In the constructor of `Nbody`, there's no need for the trailing underscore in the parameter names. The following code looks cleaner and is otherwise equivalent to your current code:

```cpp
Nbody::Nbody(int n, double dt, double t_max)
: n(n), dt(dt), t_max(t_max) {
    init_data();  // should be removed, as I said above
}
```

For debugging purposes it would be good to have not only the `timeIntegration` method, but also a simple `step` method that only does a single step. This allows you to write better unit tests. It also makes another of the constructor parameters, namely `t_max` unnecessary.

Still in `timeIntegration`, instead of `step+=1` you should write `++step`. Writing `step++` would be equivalent, but that would tell every reader that you don't know C++ well. In C++ the `++` usually comes before the variable, in other languages like Java or C or Go it usually comes after the variable. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17367081/225757) for some more details.

Comparing the code of `timeIntegration` with `update_velocity` reveals that you use an inconsistent programming style. You should decide for yourself whether to use camelCase or snake_case identifiers. Then, use that style consistently. Another thing is that you placed spaces around the operators `*` and `/`, but not around `+`. I would have expected it the other way round, since `*` and `/` bind the operands more tightly than `+`. The usual style is to always surround binary operators with spaces. Therefore `t < t_max; t += dt; step++`.

Your Nbody class does not account for tricky situations where the particles are so close together that `dt` becomes too large for a realistic simulation. This is something that you must document.

I like it that you separated `updated_velocity` and `update_position` into two separate methods. This makes them easy to read. (Plus, it's necessary from an implementation's point of view since you must first update the velocity of all particles before you can update any particle's position, otherwise the result depends on the ordering of the particles.)

The abbreviation `comp` in `comp_position` is ambiguous. It could mean compare or compute. You should spell it out.

In `Nbody::force` you should not name the parameters `i` and `j`, since these variable names are reserved for integers, by convention. I'd rather choose p and q. And if you rename `Nbody::p` to `ps` since it is plural anyway, there's no naming collision anymore.

In `write_data` the parameter `step` is not necessary since `Nbody::step` is accessible by the same name. You can just remove the parameter.

The method `print_parameter` should be called `print_parameters` since it is about *all* parameters, not just a single one.

At the API level, I would not put `dt` and `t_max` in the constructor but rather pass `dt` as parameter to the `step` method, and `t_max` as parameter to the `timeIntegration` method.

In `nbody.h` there is the `EPS` constant, which looks dubious. For a `dt` of 0.001 it may have an appropriate value of `0.0001`, but what if I want to simulate using `dt = 1.0e-9`? I don't think it should be a global constant. Not even the speed of light should be, because there are so many different speeds of light, depending on the exact experiment.

In `Nbody::init_data` you wrote `1.` without a trailing 0. Sure, it may save a single key stroke, but in my opinion it's not worth it. Just write the canonical `1.0`, as you already did in several other places in the same function.

The data you write to the `data_*.log` files is quite imprecise. The typical `double` type provides 16 to 17 digits of precision, yet you only write out 6 of them, which is the C++ default. Since 2017, [C++ finally supports printing floating point numbers accurately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370758).

Comment: C and Java both have pre-increment and post-increment just like C++ (I don't know Go, but would be surprised if that differed).  It's true to say that we generally prefer pre-increment when the value is to be discarded (though you ignore that where writing the `for` loop's increment expression - why?), and that it may be more efficient for non-inlinable types, but post-increment does have its place in C++, and should be used when it's what's required.  Perhaps that paragraph could be re-worded?

Comment: Thank you for this nice review! Is it correct to remove the trailing underscore also in the n-body class? Or is that a bad style? What do you mean by adding `dt` to the `step` method? Where would you put `EPS` then?

Comment: Yes, it's ok to remove the underscores everywhere. Regarding the `step` method: I would define `Nbody::step(double dt, double eps)`. This gives full control to the caller.

Comment: You said that `init_data()` does not belong in the `Nbody` class. Can you elaborate on this point a little? How do I initialize the particles then? Does it also make sense to add `init_data()` to the `Particle` struct?

Comment: The method `init_data` doesn't belong in the `Nbody` class because the `Nbody` has a single job: provide the physics simulation for arbitrary particles. Having particles with random masses and random locations is not generally useful. A more useful pattern is to provide a method to add a particle to the simulation. As I said, the definition of the N-body problem does not in any way contain the word "random", therefore the code shouldn't either.

Answer (score 7):

## Use a vector math library

Find a suitable library that implements coordinate vectors, so you don't have to implement them as arrays of doubles. Ideally your `struct Particle` should look like:

```
struct Particle {
    double m;   // mass
    vec3 x;     // position
    vec3 v;     // velocity
    vec3 F;     // force
    vec3 F_old; // force past time step
};
```

And a suitable library will provide functions and operator overloads to make working with these types very easy. You should be able to write something like:

```
void Nbody::update_position(Particle *p) {
    double a = dt * 0.5 / p->m;
    p->x += dt * (p->v + a * p->F);
    p->F_old = p->F;
}
```

There are many libraries available. I am partial to GLM myself. For a discussion of possible libraries, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380371/what-are-the-most-widely-used-c-vector-matrix-math-linear-algebra-libraries-a.

## Make function manipulating `Particle`s member functions of `Particle`

You have a lot of functions that mainly manipulate a particle's state, but they are not part of `struct Particle` itself. For example, `update_position()` is something that apart from the timestep `dt` only manipulates a `Particle`'s member variables. If you make it a member function of `Particle`, it becomes a much cleaner looking function:

```
struct Particle {
    ...
    void update_position(double dt);
};

void Particle::update_position(double dt) {
    double a = dt * 0.5 / m;
    x += dt * (v + a * F);
    F_old = F;
}
```

And you call it like so:

```
void Nbody::comp_position() {
    for (auto &p: particles) {
        p.update_position(dt);
    }
}
```

You can do the same for `update_velocity()`, and even `force()`.

Comment: I tried to incorporate first the second part of your answer but get the following errors: `nbody.cpp: In member function ‘void Particle::update_position(double)’:
nbody.cpp:47:33: error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
     const double a = dt * 0.5 / p->m;
                                 ^
nbody.cpp: In member function ‘void Nbody::comp_position()’:
nbody.cpp:55:19: error: ‘particles’ was not declared in this scope
     for (auto &p: particles) {
`

Comment: Is it recommended to use `for (auto &p: particles)` or is `for (Particle &p: particles)` better? When should I not use `auto`?

Comment: I recommend you use `auto` whenever the type is already clear from the context, or when you don't care about the type. Here, it should be obvious that `p` is a `Particle`, because it's an element of `particles`. Using `auto` in these cases avoids repeating types unnecessarily, and potentially avoids mistakes.

Comment: Can you please outline how you would compute the force with your approach? I have difficulties since I have in the case of the force computation a nested loop and I am not sure how to do that in this case.

Comment: Once you've written `void force(Particle &other)` as a member function of `struct Particle`, change `force(&p[i], &p[j])` to `p[i].force(p[j])` inside the nested loop. Here you should probably keep using `int i` and `int j` as iterator variables, as that's the easiest to ensure each pair is only visited once.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that I then have to use `void Particle::force(Particle& other)` and inside `force()` I remove all `i->` and replace `j->` by `other->`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Can I also use `std::array<double, DIM>` instead of a vector math library as you suggested? Could I then also get rid of the for loop?

Comment: You could use `std::valarray<>` as @Davislor suggested, but that lacks more interesting functions, like calculating the length of a vector. Math libraries will do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment due to being new here, but Roland Illig's assertion that it should be `++step` and not `step++` and that it shows that you do not understand C++ is incorrect.

In C++, the position of the `++` determines the order of how the expression is evaluated. So in `++step`, the variable is incremented before any action with it is performed, while in `step++`, the action is performed before the value is incremented. Just having a `step++` or `++step` as a single line of code is basically equivalent, but the difference is apparent in an example like so:

```
int step = 0;
std::cout << ++step << std::endl; // would print 1
std::cout << step << std::endl; // would print 1
```

while

```
int step = 0;
std::cout << step++ << std::endl; // would print 0
std::cout << step << std::endl; // would print 1
```

Just clarifying this, as you should understand the difference as opposed to preferring one over the other for stylistic/reputation reasons!

Comment: I think that Rolan Illig meant that `++i` usually is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c) than `i++`.

Comment: @eanmos, that is possible, but in the link you provided it states that this performance hit is usually only present if the type being incremented is not a primitive type. However in OP's post, `step` is of type `int`, which should be optimized correctly by the compiler.

Comment: yes, but it is a good habit to write `++i` by default and use post increment only when it is need to be used.

Comment: @eanmos fair enough. It was more of the assertion that "In C++ the ++ comes before the variable, in other languages like Java or C or Go it comes after the variable." But yes, the convention would be to use `++i`.

Comment: @eanmos Should I always use `++i` instead of `i++` in for-loops? Why is it faster?

Comment: @Samuel, in short. `i++` must create a copy of the old value, "return" it and then increment `i`. In the same time `++i` doesn't have to create a copy and "return" it, it increments `i` and just "return" it. For build-in types (such as `int`) the compiler probably be able to optimize your code. But `i` can be an instance of a C++ class so `i++` and `++i` making calls to one of the `operator++` function. In that case the compiler probably not be able to optimize and then copying of an object `i` when using `i++` can be really slow. So in general case just use `++i`.

Answer (score 3):

I will focus on one thing already addressed by another answer but that I think deserve more attention: the [Single Responsibility Principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Your `NBody` class has several functionalities merged into one, which would be advisable to separate. It, as far as I can see:

- it represent a group of N particles
- it provides the algorithm to perform the physics simulation
- it provides the facilities to print the results of the simulation

I think there is enough material to separate these into three separate entities, leaving more flexibility for changing in the future.

Also, some of the methods in your `NBody` class actually act only on the given `Particle`, so they could be refactored as methods of the `Particle` struct.

Another suggestion is to take a look at the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), which could be a useful starting point for the simulation framework to provide the right flexibility to change the integration method if it ever becomes necessary.

Comment: Do you mean by separating that I write different classes? A particle class, a simulation class and a class that prints the results?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to G. Sliepen’s idea, you could use the STL’s `std::valarray<double>`.  This would let you replace something like

```
for (int d = 0; d < DIM; ++d) {
    p->x[d] += dt * (p->v[d] + a * p->F[d]);
    p->F_old[d] = p->F[d];
}
```

with something like

```
p->F_old = p->F;
p->x += dt * (p->v + a * p->F);
```

It would also be possible to lay out a structure of arrays rather than an array of structures.  If there are more particles than dimensions, this could let you perform wider vector operations on all the x-coordinates, then all the y-coordinates and all the z-coordinates, rather than being limited to the width of the coordinate system.  That is, each `p` might have only two or three parallel computations, but if you have a number of `std::array<std::valarray<double>, DIM>` with the x-coordinates in `x[0]`, the y-coordinates in `x[1]` and the z-coordinates in `x[2]`, the velocities in `v[0]`, etc., that might look like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
  F_old[i] = F[i];
  x[i] += dt * (v[i] + a * F[i]);
}
```

and be able to use the full width of your vector registers.  This would not, however, work as well if the computations are not so cleanly separable.